# How to include jars in manifest file automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, manifest.mf

I am working with not web based application which uses bunch of external jars, we are few developers on this project and constantly add, remove jars each time jar is being added or removed we manually update manifest.mf file.
Is there any way to add jar to manifest automatically as soon as it added to a project (.classpath)?
I am using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you seem to use maven, why don't you just let maven (the maven jar plugin) create the manifest for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use eclipse, but with netbeans, you don't ever have to edit manifest files. If you still have to edit manifest files in an IDE like eclipse, then I am sure you are not using the IDE well. The IDE should handle dependencies for you without you knowing